# How can I solve this ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core' error?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to deploy a django app using docker compose. I am currently having this error when the django app image is building. Two errors that stand out in the errors below is:
`noted_app  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'` and `postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:43.169 UTC [50] FATAL:  role "noted}" does not exist`

Please how can I resolve both errors. I am currently stuck with the deployment.

```
postgres   | 
postgres   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
postgres   | 
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.060 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 (Debian 15.2-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.061 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.061 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.069 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.078 UTC [28] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-04-08 00:43:52 UTC
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:23.089 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
redis      | 1:C 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.465 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis      | 1:C 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.466 # Redis version=7.0.10, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=1, just started
redis      | 1:C 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.466 # Warning: no config file specified, using the default config. In order to specify a config file use redis-server /path/to/redis.conf
redis      | 1:M 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.468 * monotonic clock: POSIX clock_gettime
redis      | 1:M 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.474 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
redis      | 1:M 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.474 # Server initialized
redis      | 1:M 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.475 # WARNING Memory overcommit must be enabled! Without it, a background save or replication may fail under low memory condition. Being disabled, it can can also cause failures without low memory condition, see https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/issues/1328. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
redis      | 1:M 08 Apr 2023 00:44:23.477 * Ready to accept connections
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:33.056 UTC [40] FATAL:  role "noted}" does not exist
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
noted_app  | Traceback (most recent call last):
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 589, in spawn_worker
noted_app  |     worker.init_process()
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 134, in init_process
noted_app  |     self.load_wsgi()
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 146, in load_wsgi
noted_app  |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
noted_app  |     self.callable = self.load()
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
noted_app  |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
noted_app  |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
noted_app  |     mod = importlib.import_module(module)
noted_app  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
noted_app  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
noted_app  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
noted_app  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
noted_app  | [2023-04-08 00:44:34 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
noted_app exited with code 3
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:43.169 UTC [50] FATAL:  role "noted}" does not exist
postgres   | 2023-04-08 00:44:53.311 UTC [61] FATAL:  role "noted}" does not exist
```

These are my codes.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /noted

COPY . .

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 

RUN pip install -r requirements/production.txt \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install wkhtmltopdf \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /noted/noted

RUN python3 manage.py makemigrations --settings=core.settings.production

RUN python3 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --settings=core.settings.production

# Set the entry point command for gunicorn
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "core.wsgi"]
```

Docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        container_name: noted_app
        volumes:
            - ./noted:/noted
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        networks:
            - noted-network
        depends_on:
            postgres:
                condition: service_healthy

    postgres:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        tty: true
        container_name: postgres
        volumes:
            - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        networks:
            - noted-network
        env_file:
            - .env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

        healthcheck:
            test:
                [
                    "CMD-SHELL",
                    "sh -c 'pg_isready -U $DATABASE_USER} -d ${DATABASE_NAME}'"
                ]
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 3s
            retries: 3

    redis:
        image: redis
        container_name: redis
        networks:
            - noted-network
        ports:
            - 6379:6379
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        volumes:
            - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
networks:
    noted-network:
```

My .env file content

```
IP=localhost

DATABASE_NAME=noted
DATABASE_USER=noted
DATABASE_PASSWORD=noted
DATABASE_HOST=postgres
DATABASE_PORT=5432

REDIS_LOCATION="/usr/local/etc/redis"
```

Some content of my base.py which is the django settings file.

```
# Parse a `.env` file and load the variables inside into environment variables
load_dotenv()


def get_env_variable(var_name: str) -> str:
    """Get an environment variable or raise an exception."""
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = f"Set the {var_name} environment variable."
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)


# BASE_DIR: a directory where `manage.py` file.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent
PROJECT_DIR = BASE_DIR.parent

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable("SECRET_KEY")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEST_MODE = False

SITE_ID = 1

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

WSGI_APPLICATION = "core.wsgi.application"

# The project uses PostgreSQL database
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
        "NAME": get_env_variable("DATABASE_NAME"),
        "USER": get_env_variable("DATABASE_USER"),
        "PASSWORD": get_env_variable("DATABASE_PASSWORD"),
        "HOST": get_env_variable("DATABASE_HOST"),
        "PORT": get_env_variable("DATABASE_PORT"),
    }
}

REDIS_LOCATION="/usr/local/etc/redis"
```

Because the tree structure of my project might be confusing, I will be showing an image of how it is structured. The file structure can also be found here [here](https://github.com/Okeybukks/noted)
[image].